# Web API and jQuery ajax not receiving correct error

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use a jQuery ajax to call a web api method.  Using very basic methods I can not get the ajax call to return the proper response.  I have tried multiple ways thinking that it may be the response but with no luck.

Here is my code:

**Web API**

```
 // POST api/token
 public Token Post(User user)
 {
      throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));  
 }
```

**jQuery**

```
  $.ajax({
        url: http://myUrl/api/token',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function () {
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.status);
            //request.status is always 0, I am expecting 401
        }
    });
```

I have also tried using:

```
 .done(function() {
 })
 .fail(function(data) {
     //status code is always 0 instead of expected 401
  });
```

and:

```
 statusCode: {
      401: function () {
      //Never gets hit
      },
 }
```

When I check the response using Firebug in FF, I am receiving the correct response in the console:

```
 POST http://myUrl/api/token 401 Unauthorized
```

So either the satus code is always 0 or the 401 statusCode: is never hit.  What am I doing wrong and/or what do I need to do in order to properly catch the 401 error on the client?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem.  $.ajax didn't like the cross domain call.  Once I added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to the response header of my REST POST method, then I was able to get the correct data.

Comment: Thanx for your tip. I have added a sample code, so someone else could use it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Token Post(User user)
{
    Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Tried this but it did not work.  Still same problem of the client seeing status code 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = $.ajax({
    url: http://myUrl/api/token',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function () {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.status);
        //request.status is always 0, I am expecting 401
    }
});

var statusCode = result.status;
```

or alternatively:

```
$.ajax({
    url: http://myUrl/api/token',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.status);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.status);
        //request.status is always 0, I am expecting 401
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I tried both and still no luck.  I am still getting status code 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Token Post([forms body]User user)
{
  throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));  
 }
```